# Using jquery mousewheel with a slider & Jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using jQuery mousewheel to scroll on my fullscreen slider, i have added some textbox within these slides and im using jscrollpane for these text boxes, jscrollpane use also jquery mousewheel to scroll. Now if i scroll on these textboxes with mousewheel, it scrolls also my slider.

`$('#popincontent'+id).jScrollPane();`

What i want is, when i scroll within a textbox it scroll only the text box not the slider!

Thank you for your help..

Comment: Do you want something like this...? http://jsfiddle.net/Gv9Nb/18/

Comment: Prevent body to scroll when you are scrolling inside jScrollPane div!!